# Reduce waiting period for username change

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-accounts

Well, I've just changed my username, and just as I was about to change it back, I received an alert saying that I can only do so thirty days afterwards. Could it be made so that the period is shortened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Changing usernames may confuse other users, especially when done multiple times, that's why there is a waiting period. See [Can we restrict the ability of users to keep changing their names?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29966/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

I guess Stack Exchange could reduce the period from 30 to, say, 20 days. I'm not sure if that really solves your problem. Anyway, that should be a network-wide change, it's not something we can decide on Chess Stack Exchange alone.

Personally, I'd rather [get rid of the ability to change your username entirely](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3057/2378) and make it possible in extraordinary circumstances only.